# Where can I download the lxml exe file in python on the Windows?

Tags: python-2.7

I am using python 2.7 and windows 7 64bit. I want to use scrapy. But It is difficult use this. I referenced [this article](http://uzzai.com/WQwDPKy8/how-do-i-install-pyopenssl-on-windows-7-64bit.html). But I can't find the lxml installer. In here, it

```
Download and install lxml-2.3.2.win-amd64-py2.7.‌exe from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
```

But I can't find the exact file in the link. How can I download the file?

Answer (score 1):

If you have `pip`, you can just call: `pip install lxml`. (if you want a specific version, you can even request that like so: `pip install lxml==2.3.2`)

If you do not have pip, please refer to the [developer's site](http://lxml.de/installation.html) on how to build this library, or where to get pre-build versions.

Comment: I tried downloading with this script but I couldn't with this message. "  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement lxml==2.3.2 (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for lxml==2.3.2"

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/2.3, scroll down to `lxml-2.3.win32-py2.7.exe` and download/install it.

Direct link: https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/l/lxml/lxml-2.3.win32-py2.7.exe#md5=9c02aae672870701377750121f5a6f84

To get 64 bit version use this direct link (link's on the same page as the first link): https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/l/lxml/lxml-2.3.win-amd64-py2.7.exe#md5=3db458d2127e68c49d6694d409322d96